# Why does the follsolution of the ODE $x'=(t.cos(t)+sin(t),t^2.cos(t)+2t.sin(t))$, $x(0)=(0,0)$ doesn't contradict Picard?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have found the following solution:
$\varphi(t)=(t.sin(t),t^2.sin(t))$, but $\varphi(0)=\varphi(2\pi)$, while $\varphi'(0)$ and $\varphi'(2\pi)$ are linearly independent. My professor said that this answer is correct, but he told me to think a bit more why it doesn't contradict Picard's theorem. But I can't find a good reason.

Comment: Doesn't $sen(t)$ have to be $\sin(t)$ or $\sec(t)$ on your title?

Comment: @Nicco, it's sin(t), sorry.

Comment: Is the underlying equation second order? If so then something like this is actually to be expected, because a second order equation $y''=f(t,y,y')$, from the point of view of Picard-Lindelof, is really a system of two first order equations $y'=z,z'=f(t,y,z)$. That's why second order equations need an initial value and an initial derivative.

Comment: No. It's only one ODE of first order. (The one in the title)
$\varphi(t)$ is one solution for this ODE.

Comment: We have only $x'=f(t,x)$, where $f(t,x)=(t.cos(t)+sin(t),t^2.cos(t)+2t.sin(t))$ with initial value $x(0)=(0,0)$.

Comment: So it is two first order (scalar) ODEs. Moreover there is no explicit dependence on $x$. Thus the fact that $\phi(0)=\phi(2 \pi)$ but $\phi'(0) \neq \phi'(2 \pi)$ is no surprise, because the equation is not autonomous. Thinking in the autonomous framework, you can frame this as three scalar ODEs, using a dummy "time" variable $s$: $\frac{dx_1}{ds}=f_1(t,x_1,x_2),\frac{dx_2}{ds}=f_2(t,x_1,x_2),\frac{dt}{ds}=1$. Now you have an autonomous system, but the initial conditions are now *different*: $x_1$ and $x_2$ agree between the two but $t$ does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you seem to be thinking about Picard's theorem is the way one should think about it for autonomous systems. In this case, if $y$ solves your ODE and $y(a)=y(b)$, then $y'(a)=y'(b)$ is one of several consequences of Picard's theorem. This is what you seem to be expecting.

But your equation, which is (from the comments):

$$\frac{dx_1}{dt}=t \sin(t) + \cos(t) \\
\frac{dx_2}{dt}=t^2 \cos(t)+2t\sin(t)$$

is *not* autonomous. In fact it doesn't even have explicit dependence on $x$ at all. However, you can always* make an ODE autonomous by making time a dependent variable, and introducing a dummy independent variable. In your case this looks like:

$$\frac{dx_1}{ds}=t \sin(t)+\cos(t) \\
\frac{dx_2}{ds}=t^2 \cos(t)+2t\sin(t) \\
\frac{dt}{ds}=1.$$

In this formulation, your equation is autonomous, but the initial data now consist of three numbers, $(x_1(t_0),x_2(t_0),t_0)$. In your case the first two agree but the third does not, so there is no contradiction to Picard's theorem.

* This is not quite true: Picard's theorem for $y'=f(t,y)$ only requires $f$ to be continuous in $t$ and Lipschitz continuous in $y$. "Autonomization" would require $f$ to also be Lipschitz continuous in $t$. But there is no problem in your case, at least on a finite time interval.

Comment: Why the third variable of the initial value doesn't agree?

Comment: @AndréGomes One initial condition has $t=0$, the other has $t=2 \pi$.

Comment: Where did you take these values?

Comment: @AndréGomes From your original question. Basically you have two IVPs with the same equation: one with the initial condition $(0,0,0)$ and the other with the initial condition $(0,0,2 \pi)$. You are asking why they don't have the first two components of the solution do not have the same initial derivative; the reason is because (in the autonomized form) the initial conditions do not agree.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Of course. Thanks

Comment: And why did we have to "autonomize" it? I mean, once it isn't in Picard's hypothesis. The first system in your answer seems to agree with all Picard's hypothesis. One can take $x_1'=(t.sin(t)+cos(t)).1$, provided that $g(x)=1$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: @AndréGomes You don't have to autonomize, I just did it because you were thinking along those lines, and the question can be explained along those lines. If you don't autonomize, then you still need to pay attention to the fact that the IVPs $y'=f(t,y),y(t_0)=y_0$ and $y'=f(t,y),y(t_1)=y_0$ are different, and in particular are not just time shifts of one another if $f$ has any explicit dependence on $t$.